# Number of permutations with repetitions where no equivalent elements are in the same chunk

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So, let's assume we have $n$ unique symbols, and we have $k$ instances of each unique symbol.

The total amount of strings would be $$\frac{(k\cdot n)!}{(k!)^n}$$

Now lets assume that we divide the strings by equal chunks of size $m$ where $n\cdot k$ is divisable by $m$ and $m \le k$. *What is the number of strings such that no chunk has multiple instances of the same symbol?*

In particular, if we assume $n=4, k = 3, m = 2$ the following string would be excluded:

```
aa ab bc bd cd cd
```

Only because the first chunk has two `a` in it.

Can this question be answered generally only by using closed forms over elementary functions and factorials? If not, what is the best approximation in such functions?

Comment: Interesting. If $m=3$ is $aab$ allowed? You mean all the chunk is with same elements or you mean at least $2$ of the same elements discard it?

Comment: @Phicar, no, $aab$ is not allowed. All symbols should be different within the chunk.